# Automatically repeating values in Word

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have a Word doc where I keep a matrix listing dates and other data. I would like for some of the data to appear in other portions of the document. Obviously, this can be done manually, but this would be running the risk of data being inconsistent if the user doesn't remember to update the other areas where the data needs to appear as well. Does anybody know of a way to tell Word to repeat the same data in a specified location? My fear is, the fact that the source of the data is a matrix would add a layer of complexity by having to tell Word exactly which cell to reference.

If this were Excel, it would be a lot easier. The Excel counterpart would be the formula =A1...so whatever value I enter in A1 would be duplicated in the cell that carries the formula. Hopefully this analogy explains my issue if my rambling above doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom Value. You can Create / Define from menu:

```
File -> Info -> Properties -> Advanced -> TAB Custom -> Create one... (Custom1)
```

To insert:

```
Insert -> Quick Parts -> Field (Custom1)
```

Inside DocProperty (field name) you found the Field.
You can insert a lot inside you doc. Every you want to have the same value.
After you can use a code like:

```
Dim oStory As Range

Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("Custom1").Value = InputBox("Valore")
For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    oStory.Fields.Update
    If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
        While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
            oStory.Fields.Update
        Wend
    End If
Next oStory
Set oStory = Nothing
```

to modify and update ALL the field (with same name).